# Mix string and List into a List

Tags: csv, f#

I have this function that writes to an csv file.
the output of the csv file should be like this.

```
title(string) body(string) images(list) variations(list)
ipsum1        lorem1       img1         variation1
empty         empty        img2         variation2
empty         empty        img3         variation3
```

The function I'm trying to use is something like this.

```
    let col1 = ["title"; title]
    let col2 = ["body"; stringedBody]
    let col3 = ["images", images] //LIST  
    let col4 = ["allVariations",allVariations] //LIST
                   
    let cols = [col1; col2; col3; col4; ] //*col3 & 4 gives all elements must be of the same type as the first element, witch here is 'string' . This element has type 'string * string list*'

    let transpose(xs: string list list) : string list list =
        [0 .. xs.[0].Length - 1] |> List.map (fun i ->
        xs |> List.rev |> List.fold (fun acc col -> col.[i] :: acc) [] 
        )

    let stringify_rows(xs: string list list) : string list =
        xs |> List.map (fun row -> System.String.Join(";", row))

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("\\test.csv", cols |> transpose |> stringify_rows)
```

But the problem seems to be with column 3 and 4, I have also tried to create an array of the images

```
let mutable img = [|images|]
```

but that gave me an similar error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process a list of things in F# in a uniform way, then all the things in your list need to be of the same type. This is not the case in your example. You use a list of strings in some cases (when you have different values for each row) but just a single string in other cases (when there is the same value for all rows).

The best way to fix your logic is to come up with a uniform representation. I think the easiest option is to use a list of `string option` values. Then you can use `Some "str"` for a value and `None` for a missing value:

```
let col1 = [Some "title"; Some "lorem"; None; None]
let col2 = [Some "body"; Some "ipsum"; None; None]
let col3 = [Some "images"; Some "img1"; Some "img2"; Some "img3"]
let col4 = [Some "allVariations"; Some "var1"; Some "var2"; Some "var3"]
```

With this, most of your code (almost) works! The only change is that you need to make `transpose` compatible with `string option`. You can do that by changing the annotation to `'a list list`:

```
let transpose(xs: 'a list list) : 'a list list =
    [0 .. xs.[0].Length - 1] |> List.map (fun i ->
    xs |> List.rev |> List.fold (fun acc col -> col.[i] :: acc) [] 
    )
```

I also changed `stringify_rows` to add an empty string as the default value for missing values:

```
let stringify_rows(xs: string option list list) : string list =
    xs |> List.map (fun row -> 
      row |> List.map (Option.defaultValue "") |> String.concat ";")
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I still get the same error when I add the images variable to col3 

let col3 = [Some "images"; Some images]
This expression was expected to have a type 'string' but here has a type 'string list'